# Jupyter Notebooks stuck at In[*]:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-3.7

I reinstalled Anaconda with base Python 3.7. In my base environment, my Jupyter notebooks will not work. I receive the following error in my prompt as I'm trying to run the notebook:

[I 19:07:37.057 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 39b758d6-fcaa-4f2d-b10f-235ad7b39292:2380a18e272242638ff4fe4d9e628719

[I 19:07:38.115 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 39b758d6-fcaa-4f2d-b10f-235ad7b39292

[I 19:07:38.121 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for 39b758d6-fcaa-4f2d-b10f-235ad7b39292:2380a18e272242638ff4fe4d9e628719

This occurs with something as simple as print('World') or any code.

The errors just continue to loop. I've search GitHub and StackOverflow and have yet to find a real solution. Any help with this?? Thanks! FYI: I'm using 64-bit Windows 10.

Comment: For an update, I have reinstalled different python versions, checked my port, used old version, and have had several software engineers look at my computer. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: One thing I notice in 'About' under the Notebook the kernel status is always 'Waiting for kernel to be available..'

In the anaconda prompt, port 8888 is usually unavailable, so it switches to the next and seems to connect okay.

Comment: After some time, I also usually get a Websocket timeout (after ~9000 ms).

Answer (score 1):

Solved on my laptop by uninstalling antivirus.

My antivirus was actually causing Jupyter to not be able to use my system-level kernel. I believe this is due to Jupyter's browser-based nature. (FYI: I was using ad-aware free)